# Where are the templates for the Laravel Voyager admin stored?

Tags: laravel, templates, admin, voyager

I have a very hard time looking for them either online and offline without finding nothing. No information on the internet. No trace of the Voyager package in

- Vendor
- Resources/Views
- Providers

Any information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy manually from `vendor/tcg/voyager/resources/views` to `resources/views/vendor/voyager`.

here is my copied folder:

[image]

Normally, packages have publisher for the views that you can publish it. Should be like `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="providerpath" --tag="views"`. But unfortunately, `VoyagerServiceProvider` doesn't have that publish tag.